# How can we solve the expression explicitly for $X$ in terms of $Y$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

I am thinking how to write $X$ explicitly in terms of $Y,A,B,C$?

I have $AX^3 + X^2(B-1) + X(-C) + \alpha = Y$

I thought of using symbolic maths but could not find any.

Any help is nice!

Comment: Isn't this a cubic equation, for which you can find the solutions online?

Comment: It would be much helpful if you could please give me the link, but we note that $A,B,C,\alpha$ are all symbolic variables and hence do not have explicit values, I am trying to get a generalized expression of $x$ in terms of $A,B,C,\alpha, y$

Comment: see here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html or if you have Mathematica / Octave / other symbolic software you can try there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the solutions of cubic equation, you eed to follow the steps described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function).

Applied to the case of your equation
$$A x^3 +(B-1)x^2 -C x + (\alpha-y) = 0$$ because the formula are quite nasty, I strongly suggest that you start defining some intermediate coefficients such as, for example,
$$b=\frac{B-1}A \qquad c=-\frac C A\qquad d=\frac {\alpha-y} A$$ (assuming $A \neq 0$) to make the equation
$$x^3+b x^2+c x+d=0$$

Now, you will need to compute the key quantities
$$\Delta =b^2 c^2+18 b c d-4 c^3-27 d^2-4 b^3 d$$
$$p=c-\frac{b^2}{3}$$
$$q=\frac{2 b^3}{27}-\frac{b c}{3}+d$$ and follow the steps given in the linked page.

If you are only concerned by the possible single real solution (this implies $\Delta <0$), use what is given in the *"hyperbolic solution for one real root"* paragraph. It could be a nasty formula but totally workable.

If you face three real solutions  (this implies $\Delta >0$), use what is given in the
*"trigonometric solution for three real roots"* paragraph. It could be a nasty formula but totally workable.

Comment: @nitsua60. Thanks for pointing the typo ! Cheers :-)